# Firewall and virus software for Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: firewall, scanner, firestarter

I've only used a window operating systems in my life. I just began using Ubuntu 14.10 about a week ago after my old Windows OS was corrupted.  Using Ubuntu 14.10, how does change the firewall settings?  I'm unable to locate the the old Firestarter firewall program I've read about.  Also, virus scanning software, is this necessary with Ubuntu?  I've read of a virus software called ClamAV and ClamTK, but i think i am reading from an outdated book.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

[Firewall settings](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) in Ubuntu can be customized using [Firewall Configuration](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gufw/) Software or using [command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html).
Besides if you are normal user you need not to worry about firewall, because the default settings are pretty safe. If you want to play around you can use above links.
*There are only 100 or so viruses for linux. And changes of them to be distributed on internet is very very small, so don't be scared and keep your system up-to-date and disable autoplay* from System Settings > Details > Removable Media.
[ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/index.html) could be use to scan your files for viruses or malware, specially those files that are downloaded from *downloading sites* or email. Besides if you visit only popular sites (Google, youtube etc) you need not to worry about viruses. ClamAV can be sometimes used to scan windows partition.